# Can I extend the .click method of a WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to extend the .click method of a WebElement?

I would like to add a few lines of code to it to accommodate some issues we have with an internal website.

I would like to add:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(pageElement));
```

Now I know that some of you will probably say just use implicit wait.  I've thought about that but some of the pages I code against take 10-30 seconds to load.  Some of the pages load very quickly but then the buttons that get displayed are conditional based on clicking other buttons and I get into a situation where I know the button should have loaded within 5 seconds.  I'd rather not incur the 30 second wait on every button.  This could happen literally hundreds of times and I don't want the script to take that long.

Is there a way to add an explicit wait to a click event?

Comment: In C# I would just override the method but I don't know how to do that in Java.

Comment: Why dont you create a static utility method that wraps the click() with the additional functionality you want.

Comment: You should not customize a general method to solve specific issues, this is  not a good practice. Use page objects and treat in those specific actions the issues that you have.

Comment: @lauda normally I would agree with you but in this case to add code for each button (there are hundreds) will literally add thousands of lines of code.  I created a class and then pass the element into it and then do what I need to do but the code isn't as readable as I would like it to be.

Comment: @Grasshopper can you offer an example?

Comment: public static void clickWithWait(WebDriver driver, int timeout, WebElement pageElement, ExpectedCondition<WebElement> condition) {WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
wait.until(condition); pageElement.click();} You can reduce the number of arguments. If you are using pageobjects then you can make this non-static and include it in a base pageobject class.

Answer (score 0):

Try FluentWait, This will check for element every 5 seconds.

```
Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver).withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a need to override `.click()` and as @lauda has stated in the comments, this is not a good practice. You don't need to add a lot of code to wait for the element to be clickable so the claim that it will add thousands of lines of code is not true. You can easily accomplish this with a single line of code... so no extra lines of code. Having said that... you should focus less on how many lines of code it will add and consider:

1. How easy is it going to be to maintain?
2. Am I adding unnecessary complexity to my code base?
3. Is it going to be more readable?
4. ...and so on...

A sample click method for a representative button

```
public void clickButtonX()
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, timeOutInSeconds).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(buttonXLocator)).click();
}
```

where you have these declared at the top of the class

```
private By buttonXLocator = By.id("buttonXId");
private int timeOutInSeconds = 10;
```

Having said that... I don't think this is the right approach. With the page object model, you should have each page class handle waiting for the page to finish loading... then you won't have to wait for the buttons to load before clicking them. In the case where a button is loaded dynamically, the action that triggers the dynamic loading should wait for the load to complete.

```
package sandbox;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import common.Functions;

public class _PageTemplate
{
    private WebDriver driver;
    private By dynamicPageLoadLocator = By.id("someId");
    private By buttonXLocator = By.id("buttonXId");
    private By dynamicLinkLocator = By.id("dynamicLinkId");
    private By dynamicSectionElementLocator = By.id("dynamicSectionId");

    public _PageTemplate(WebDriver webDriver) throws IllegalStateException
    {
        Functions.waitForPageLoad(driver);

        // see if we're on the right page
        if (!driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("samplePage.jsp"))
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the XXXX Sample page. Current URL: " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
        }

        // for dynamic pages, wait for a specific element to signal the dynamic load is complete
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(dynamicPageLoadLocator));
    }

    public void clickButtonX()
    {
        // no wait needed here
        driver.findElement(buttonXLocator).click();
    }

    public void clickDynamicLink()
    {
        // clicking this link triggers part of the page to change, reload, etc. ...
        driver.findElement(dynamicLinkLocator).click();
        // ... so after the click, we wait for the dynamic part of the page to finish by locating an element that is inside the dynamically
        // loaded portion and wait for it to be visible
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(dynamicSectionElementLocator));
    }
}
```

where this is declared in some Utils class or whatever.

```
/**
 * Waits for the browser to signal that the DOM is loaded. For dynamic pages, an extra wait may be necessary.
 */
public static void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver driver)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
    {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver webDriver)
        {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    });
}
```

Now with this framework, we no longer have to add code to each button to make sure that it's available before the click. I would suggest you take this approach to all your code. Wait only in the places it's needed rather than sprinkling waits everywhere.

1. Wait for the page to load
2. After triggering a dynamic page change, wait for the page change to complete

If you just do those two things, you will only have waits in very specific places and not need them everywhere (reducing complexity and confusion when debugging, etc.).